# How to reload / refresh an iron-list in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have added an item to my *data* property bound to an `iron-list`.

```
this.data.push(item); // add new item to array
```

Now the *data* item has been added but the list will not refresh / reload to show new item added to *data* array. How do you reload the iron-list? Also couldn't seem to find a method on the [iron-list API page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list). I've tried the following but with no joy...

```
var list = this.querySelector("iron-list");
list.fire('refresh');
list._refresh();
```

My data property is defined as follows:

```
Polymer({
  is: "page-list",
  properties: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      notify: true
    }
```

The template structure is:

```
<iron-ajax url="./data.json" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
<iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item" class="fit">
  <template>
    <div class="row">
      <p>[[item.name]]</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

Comment: Tip: if iron-list is hidden you might need to call `list.fire('resize')` after shown to display items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use a *Polymer* function to add a new item, like this -

```
this.push('data', item);
```

> Mutations to the items array itself (push, pop, splice, shift,
>   unshift) must be performed using methods provided on Polymer elements,
>   such that the changes are observable to any elements bound to the same
>   array in the tree.

You can read more from [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html).

Comment: Should this also work if I replace a binding model with this.set('data', someNewArray)?

Comment: One more thing... If I resize the browser window and text reflows inside an iron-list my list items start to overlap as the row heights change. How can I refresh the iron-list view when the window is resized?

Comment: ^ just found solution in the iron-list source: `document.querySelector('iron-list').fire('iron-resize');`

Comment: You can also use `this.querySelector('iron-list').notifyResize();` check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009715/how-to-sort-an-iron-list-in-polymer-1-0/35329297#35329297) for custom sorting.

Comment: This solution does not work. Nor does over riding dirty checking.