# How to sort an iron-list in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am looking to sort data in an iron-list (and also sort items as they are added into the data array).

Sample (unsorted) json data:

```
[
  {"name": "Zebra"},
  {"name": "Alligator"},
  {"name": "Lion"}
]
```

I have tried using the `indexAs` property to sort an `iron-list` as follows but the [API](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list) isn't clear how to use it:

```
<iron-ajax url="./data.json" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>
<iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item" index-as="name" class="fit">
  <template>
    <div>
      Name: <span>[[item.name]]</span>
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

Comment: `index-as` is used to that you can bind the index variable to something more meaningfull to print the index out on screen. You will probably want to use a function instead that returns your data in the sorted form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if there's more native *Polymer* way to do this, but it's not too complex to build the sorting logic yourself.

The idea is to listen to the `response` event, sort the data from the service and then bind the `items` of the `iron-list` to the `sortedData`.

You will need to add `on-response="_onResponseReceived"` to your `iron-ajax`. And then it's just a matter of sorting the returned data.

```
_onResponseReceived: function () {
    this.sortedData = this.data.sort(this._compare);
},

_compare: function (a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name)
        return -1;
    if (a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course the `iron-list` now needs to be updated to

```
<iron-list items="[[sortedData]]" ...>
```

Comment: What if your data source is `<firebase-collection>` instead of `<iron-ajax>`? Any ideas for that case?

Comment: @Mowzer, I haven't used `<firebase-collection>` but I guess there must be an event similar to `response`?

Comment: No. `<firebase-collection>` doesn't implement ajax in the usual way. It's a  databinding. It uses a state-driven approach. (Not event-driven like regular ajax). You're either (quasi-continuously) "connected" or not. There is a `disconnect()` method but I don't think that's useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

With Polymer 1.2.4 if you want to sort an `iron-list` in a dynamic fashion you can also take advantage of `this.querySelector('iron-list').notifyResize();` to force a refresh after you update the `sortedItems` array in your observer. This is a hack but if you don't do this unfortunately polymer doesn't refresh the list for you. Let's sort by `id` or `name` our items:

```
<template>
    <paper-icon-button icon="expand-more" on-tap="_sortItems" sort-option="id"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="expand-more" on-tap="_sortItems" sort-option="name"></paper-icon-button>

    <iron-list items="[[sortedItems]]">
        <template>
            <p>[[item.name]]<p>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
</template>
...
properties: {
    ...
    sortByTerm: {
        type: String,
        value: 'id'
    },
    sortByOrder: {
        type: Number,
        value: -1 // Descending order
    },
},
observers: [
    'sortingObserver(items.*, sortByTerm, sortByOrder)'
],
sortingObserver: function(items, sortByTerm, sortByOrder) {
    var sortedItems = [],
    validSortingOptions = ['id', 'name'];

    if (validSortingOptions.indexOf(sortByTerm) != -1) {
        sortedItems = items.base.sort(this._computeSort(sortByTerm, sortByOrder));
    } else {
        sortedItems = items.base;
    }

    this.set('sortedItems', sortedItems);
    this.querySelector('iron-list').notifyResize();
},
_computeSort: function(property, order) {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (a[property] === b[property]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (order * (a[property] > b[property] ? 1 : -1));
    };
},
_sortItems: function(e) {
    var sortByTerm = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('sort-option');
    this.set('sortByTerm', sortByTerm);
},
...
```